# What is best pythonic way to communicate between spreaded services/unix machines?

Tags: python, django, unix, tcp, communication

Mornink!

I need to design, write and implement wide system consisting of multiple unix servers performing different roles and running different services. The system must be bullet proof, robust and fast. Yeah, I know. ;) Since I dont know how to approach this task, I've decided to ask you for your opinion before I leave design stage. Here is how the workflow is about to flow:

- users are interacting with website, where they set up demands for service
- this demand is being stored (database?) and some kind of message to central system (clustered) is being sent about new demand in database/queue
- central system picks up the demand and sends signals to various other systems (clusters) to perform their duties (parts of the demanded service setup)
- when they are done, they send up message to central system or the website that the service is now being served

Now, what is the modern, robust, clean and efficient way of storing these requests in some kind of queue, and executing them? Should I send some signals, or should I let all subsystems check the queue/db of any sort for new data? What could be that queue, should it be a database? How to deal with the messages? I thought about opening single tcp connection and sending data over that, along with comands triggering actions/functions on the other end, but at closer inspection, there has to be other, better way. So I found Spring Python, that has been criticized for being so 90's-ish.

I know its a very wide question, but I really hope you can help me wrap my head around that design and not make something stupid here :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Some general ideas for you:
You could have a master-client approach. Requests would be inserted in the master, stored in a database. Master knows the state of each client (same db). Whenever there is a request, the master redirects it to a free client. The client reports back when has finished the task (including answers if any), making it able to receive a new task from the master (this removes the need for pooling). 
Communication could be done using web-services. An HTTP request/post should solve every cases. No need to actually go down to the TCP level.

Just general ideas, hope they're useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of message queue technologies out there which are Python friendly which could serve quite well.  The top two that I know of are [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) and [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), which both play well with Python, plus I found [this comparison](http://www.nighttale.net/activemq/python-messaging-activemq-and-rabbitmq.html) which states that ActiveMQ currently (as of 18 months ago!) outperforms RabbitMQ.

Comment: Could you repaste the comparison link? It doesnt work currently.

Comment: @SpankMe - ha, indeed, had a copy/paste error :)  sorry about that, it's updated now

Comment: Thanks! However, I am not sold on the idea, mostly beacuse I dont get any pros/cons of such solution. These *MQ techniques are applying extra layer of complexity bringing new variable. I am thinking about something darn simple - such things are usually most robust and fast. Cant see why this cant (or shouldnt) be done with simple Spring Python... I think I am a bit lost here, trying to choose the technology ;)